# Disable horizontal gestures in VLC on OS X

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, vlc-media-player

Is there any non-violant way to disable horizontal scrolling in VLC (`2.0.6`) on OS X Mountain Lion? I went through the Preferences but couldn't find anything concerning the matter.

I could do something with AppleScript, but I'm wondering if it's just possible within VLC itself.

The reason I want to disable it is that when I accidentally don't fully gesture to another "space" (two fingers) I will mess up the play-position inside VLC.

Comment: Does anyone here know how to disable the gestures in VLC 2.2.4? I tried what was suggested in the top answer, but I couldn't find anything that looked like "MouseWheel up-down axis Control" in the preferences.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This answer concerns VLC 2.0.7, but may work for previous versions.

In the menu bar select `VLC -> Preferences`

Then press `Show All`

Navigate to `Interface -> Hotkey Settings -> Hotkeys`

And change `MouseWheel up-down axis Control` to `Ignore`

Then restart VLC (`VLC-> Quit`)

This option is not well named as it only specifies the up-down axis. However, setting it to ignore disables both the up-down and left-right axis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer eltommo. It indeed disables the vertical gestures for volume control too. It's not that bad tho, I'm mostly concerned about the horizontal as it often accidentally scrolls my VLC movie when try to swap another Space in OSX.

Comment: @Allender Yeah, the accidental skipping was driving me insane; it's worth sacrificing the volume control in my opinion.

Comment: Definitely agree :)

Comment: Skipping is not as bad as blowing ears when using earphones, or the speakers at 200% volume, or which ever comes first :).  Very useful when watching screencasts where you instinctively try to scroll what's in a video.

Comment: Does this still work for people? I have both set to ignore and I can still scroll to seek and change the volume.

Answer (score 0):

For Catalina (10.15) and VLC (3.0.11.1):

`VLC > Preferences > Show All > Interface > Hotkeys settings > Mouse wheel horizontal axis control > Ignore`

Then `Save`.

(You might need to completely exit the app and restart it to have effect.)